# Jquery fullcalendar custom event tile stacking in agenda day view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar for sharepoint since it's fully open source.

I am trying to create an agenda day view where i can limit the number events that will horizontally stack in a time row before the row multiplies in height and further events begin stacking in the newly increased row but below the previous events in that row.

Basically we want a horizontal limit that when exceeded will grow the time slot row to accept more events. This way a single time row could contain multiple subrows of events.

The structure of the HTML for this and the standard sharepoint calendar make this difficult to do with JS modification on the page after it's already generated.

Comment: will you please elaborate more. didn't understand

Comment: can you show a screenshot / diagram of what you mean? From your description I can't quite make out the scenario. Are you asking if there's a way to limit how wide the calendar gets? Also, have you tried anything so far in order to attempt to resolve it? There'd be no point in going over old ground, so please mention anything you've done already.

Comment: Will put up a screenshot when I get home.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oXcwosh

When there are more than 3 events that would occupy the same time slot, I want to multiply the height of the time row and stack the events underneath the previous events like such.

The FullCalendar.js script is 15000+ lines of function after function that just calls other functions and tracking it all down is a bit ridiculous. Every little action is its own function. Given my relative inexperience at webdev, this is making things difficult.

I know I am looking in the right place at "TimeGridEventRenderer.prototype.computeFgSegHorizontals = function (segs)"